# Strange usage of the verb "breed"

Tags: prepositions

**Sentence:**

> Although he was bred __ the law, he became a successful journalist.

**Problem:** Fill in the blank with apt. preposition.

**Attempt:** I have no idea. Even my 1500 page Oxford dictionary doesn't have a usage of the verb "breed" which might suit the sentence here :/ My best guess can be "with" or "under" but I don't know if it's correct.

**Question:** What is the correct answer here and why?

Comment: Maybe the use is metaphorical here? "Although he was bred **for** the law", meaning "he was educated to become a lawyer"? I googled and found only 9 exampes for "bred for the law". A quote: "*Allan was bred for the law, but forsook it, and retired to the country.*"

Comment: As @CopperKettle mentioned, it is 'for'.   https://targetstudy.com/languages/english/preposition-exercise-4.html

Comment: I'll convert the comment into an answer then.

Comment: It would be "bred **to** the law"  -- a turn of phrase popular in the 19th century. Tell your teachers to find new textbooks, or your examiners to get with it. :)

Comment: @TRomano - "bred to the law" brings up 181 results on Google Books. But  "bred for the law" is still used in 3 books. Anyway, it's a strange test, asking for a quaint expression.

Comment: Animals and crops are "bred **for**".  People are figuratively "bred **to**". But as I said, it's a quaint phrase for 2016. You'll find it in Nathaniel Hawthorne.

Comment: @TRomano So, should I go with the old phrase bred to or the bred for?

Comment: If you want to be in the mainstream (of the 19th century) choose **to**. That website must have plucked its exercises from a book now in the public domain because its copyright had run out.

Answer (score 3):

CopperKettle has answered your question about the preposition, but also note that one of Dictionary.com's definitions for 'breed' is "to develop by training or education; bring up; rear: 'He was born and bred a gentleman'.", so 'bred for the law' means something like 'He came from a family of lawyers and/or was intended or encouraged by them to become one'. This usage of 'breed' is almost always past tense and passive. His pregnant mother would not have said 'We are going to breed him for the law'.

Comment: But the father might have said to his wife before she became pregnant, "If you bear me a son, my dear, he will be bred to the law, as I was, and my father and grandfather before me."